# set screen resolution higher than what's supported

Tags: resolution, lubuntu, xrandr

When I run `xrandr` I have this output:

```
barsoom@ubuntu:/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu$ sudo xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       75.0*    70.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.0     60.0     56.0     65.0  
   640x480        75.0     73.0     67.0     60.0
```

How do I change it higher than what's available? I need to set it to the resolution of my monitor, `1440x900` because everything looks so big.

---

What I Tried:

these command:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "VGA1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode default 1440x900
```

Answer (score -1):

See this post for a clear solution [www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-11-04-a-878836/](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-11-04-a-878836/)